# detecting when you are going to reach your hit limit for Google Analytics free account

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, page-views

I am a user of a free Google Analytics account and i'm slightly concerned that I may be approaching the 10,000,000 hit (Pageviews, Events etc) per month.

Google state in [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/limits-quotas):

> These limits apply to the Web Property / Property / Tracking ID.
>
> ```
> 10 million hits per month per property
> ```
>
> If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you
>   and ask you upgrade to Premium or implement client sampling to reduce
>   the amount of data being sent to Google Analytics.

However, I note that there is nothing to say that you can review or check up on your current usage for the month. I have administrator access to the Google Analytics account, but I see no feature that lets me check up on my monthly usage. I don't know if Google offer this, either by means of the admin interface or via their support channels - but it would certainly be a useful feature.

Is there anyway for a free GA user to obtain this information?

Comment: Congratulations! This is a nice problem to have :) Good question though.

Comment: Surely this is just current page views for the month then - 10,000,000 = how many you have left....

Comment: @bybe it depends on what is considered a "hit" - if it is multiple items (Pageviews, Events etc) it could be tedious to manually add the information together, and you still might not be sure you considered everything.

Comment: Well I'd consider 1 page view, 1 event = 2 - 10,000,000 so ya it should be page views + events - 10,000,000 but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: @bybe Like I say in the question a "hit" includes pageviews and events, so it's not just a limit on the pageviews.

Comment: i don't think so they apply this rule. once upon a time i was having about 2 million page impressions per day. right now it is about 130k. never got contacted

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG But they may "implement client sampling to reduce the amount of data being sent"

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do is use the [GA Core Reporting API](http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to extract these numbers automatically. It's not very easy to build the queries manually, so I use the [Google Analytics Query Explorer 2](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).

I think you need the metrics you need are the metrics: `ga:pageviews,ga:visits`

You can find a go reference implementation for pulling the data from Google Analytics on Google Code, links can be found it the GA CR API

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, surely

```
number of page views + number of events
```

Please can you explain what you find lacking in that logic? Also

```
If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you
```

**might** contact you, it doesn't say that is is a hard and fast limit; Also it is very likely that it is based on an average of a few months, for example years ago when the limit was 5M a month, I had a site hit 6M and not get contacted, it just had an unusual peak here and there because of digg traffic

If I were you I would do a total for 2013 and work out the average PV + Events per day, and times by 30 and go off that figure. If that figure is knocking on 10M then it will likely be time to come up with a plan b!

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics, you can specify the dates you would like to see information for. It should be in the top right corner of your dashboard.

Then, under Standard Reports, the Audience Overview link should take you to see the amount of visitors that have seen your site within that time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom report==>select metric hits==>and any dimension I took user type and you will get a number of hits.[image]